# Webpack refuses execute script because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I use Webpack bundler and Webpack dev server for local development. The entry point is some html file. The local host dev server runs ok and the html and css are loaded correctly, however the typescript file that is embed using a script tag inside the html refuses to load and this error is printed to the chorme console - Refused to execute script from 'http://10.100.102.10:8080/b2719c17562cf8ee.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the webpack configuration files I use:

1 - webpack.common.js (used by dev and prod files)

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../products/products.html'),    
    output:
    {
        hashFunction: 'xxhash64',
        filename: 'bundle.[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist')
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins:
    [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../assets') }
            ]
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../products/products.html'),
            minify: true
        }),
        new MiniCSSExtractPlugin()
    ],
    module:
    {
        rules:
        [
            // HTML
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use:
                [
                    'html-loader'
                ]
            },

            // JS
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:
                [
                    'babel-loader'
                ]
            },

            // TS
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,                
                use:
                [
                    'ts-loader'
                ]
            },
            // CSS
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use:
                [
                    MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },

            // Images
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator:
                {
                    filename: 'assets/images/[hash][ext]'
                }
            },

            // Fonts
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator:
                {
                    filename: 'assets/fonts/[hash][ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2 - webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require('path')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const commonConfiguration = require('./webpack.common.js')
const portFinderSync = require('portfinder-sync')

const infoColor = (_message) =>
{
    return `\u001b[1m\u001b[34m${_message}\u001b[39m\u001b[22m`
}

module.exports = merge(
    commonConfiguration,
    {
        stats: 'errors-warnings',
        mode: 'development',
        infrastructureLogging:
        {
            level: 'warn',
        },
        devServer:
        {
            host: 'local-ip',
            port: portFinderSync.getPort(8080),
            open: true,
            https: false,
            allowedHosts: 'all',
            hot: false,
            watchFiles: ['../src/**', '../../assets/**'],
            static:
            {
                watch: true,
                directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../assets')
            },
            client:
            {
                logging: 'none',
                overlay: true,
                progress: false
            },
            setupMiddlewares: function (middlewares, devServer)
            {
                console.log('------------------------------------------------------------')
                console.log(devServer.options.host)
                const port = devServer.options.port
                const https = devServer.options.https ? 's' : ''
                const domain1 = `http${https}://${devServer.options.host}:${port}`
                const domain2 = `http${https}://localhost:${port}`

                console.log(`Project running at:\n  - ${infoColor(domain1)}\n  - ${infoColor(domain2)}`)

                return middlewares
            }
        }
    }
)
```

3 - In package.json I have this script :

```
webpack serve --config src/bundler/webpack.dev.js
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is actually a minimal reproducible example as far as I know.